net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: $P{timbrado}
Esta es la vista que tengo en mi proyecto django, básicamente sirve para compilar algunos reportes en jrxml, obtener los datos de un xml y posteriormente generar el pdf de los reportes de jaspersoft
from django.http import HttpResponse
import os
from pyreportjasper import PyReportJasper

def generar_pdf(request):
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    RESOURCES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Reports', '80010184-7')
    input_file = os.path.join(RESOURCES_DIR, 'SimpleReport.jrxml')
    output_file = os.path.join(RESOURCES_DIR, 'output')

    # Forzar el parámetro timbrado manualmente
    parameters = {
        'timbrado': 16313356  # Un valor de prueba para timbrado
    }

    # Configurar el classpath
    java_classpath = ":".join([
        '/mnt/data/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar',
        '/mnt/data/commons-collections4-4.2.jar',
        '/mnt/data/commons-digester-2.1.jar',
        '/mnt/data/commons-lang-2.6.jar',
        '/mnt/data/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar',
        '/mnt/data/ecj-3.21.0.jar',
        '/mnt/data/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'
    ])
    os.environ["CLASSPATH"] = java_classpath

    # Verificar todos los parámetros antes de configurar PyReportJasper
    for key, value in parameters.items():
        print(f"Parameter: {key}, Value: {value}, Type: {type(value)}")

    # Debugging: Print classpath
    print(f"CLASSPATH: {os.environ['CLASSPATH']}")

    pyreportjasper = PyReportJasper()

    try:
        pyreportjasper.config(
            input_file=input_file,
            output_file=output_file,
            output_formats=["pdf"],
            parameters=parameters
        )
        print("PyReportJasper configured successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error configuring PyReportJasper:", e)
        return HttpResponse("Error configuring PyReportJasper: {}".format(e), status=500)

    # Generar el reporte
    try:
        pyreportjasper.process_report()
        print("Report generated successfully.")
    except NameError as e:
        print("Error generating report (NameError):", e)
        return HttpResponse("Error generating report (NameError): {}".format(e), status=500)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error generating report:", e)
        return HttpResponse("Error generating report: {}".format(e), status=500)

    # Leer y devolver el archivo PDF generado
    try:
        pdf_file_path = output_file + '.pdf'
        with open(pdf_file_path, 'rb') as pdf_file:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf_file.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="output.pdf"'
            print("PDF file generated and ready to be sent.")
            return response
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error reading PDF file:", e)
        return HttpResponse("Error reading PDF file: {}".format(e), status=500)

Y esto es una de las carpetas que extrae los datos de un xml, podrás ver que son bastantes, el problema que tengo es que extrae correctamente como integer el 'timbrado', pero luego me lanza una exception de jasper
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import datetime

def remove_namespace(tree):
    for elem in tree.iter():
        if '}' in elem.tag:
            elem.tag = elem.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # Remove namespace
        for name, value in list(elem.attrib.items()):
            if '}' in name:
                new_name = name.split('}', 1)[1]
                elem.attrib[new_name] = value
                del elem.attrib[name]

def get_text(element, xpath, default=''):
    result = element.find(xpath)
    return result.text if result is not None else default

#Solo sirve para el puto cdc xd
def get_attribute(element, xpath, attribute, default=''):
    result = element.find(xpath)
    return result.attrib.get(attribute, default) if result is not None else default

def safe_int(value, default=0):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return default

def parse_date(date_str):
    try:
        date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        return date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return '1970-01-01'

def extraer_xml(file_path):
    tree = ET.parse(file_path)
    remove_namespace(tree)
    root = tree.getroot()

    data = {
        'cdc': get_attribute(root, './/DE', 'Id'),
        'rucEmi': get_text(root, './/dRucEm'),
        'timbrado': safe_int(get_text(root, './/dNumTim', 0)),
        'dDirEmi': get_text(root, './/dDirEmi', ''),
        'dTelEmi': get_text(root, './/dTelEmi', ''),
        'dEmailE': get_text(root, './/dEmailE', ''),
        'dDesActEco': get_text(root, './/dDesActEco', ''),
        'empresa': get_text(root, './/dNomEmi', ''),
        'fechaDE': parse_date(get_text(root, './/dFeEmiDE')),
        'nroFac': get_text(root, './/dNumDoc'),
        'tipDE': get_text(root, './/dDesTiDE').upper(),
        'dexp': get_text(root, './/dPunExp'),
        'dsuc': get_text(root, './/dEst'),
        'moneda': get_text(root, './/dDesMoneOpe'),
        'cambio': get_text(root, './/dTiCam', '0'),
        'condicion': get_text(root, './/dDCondOpe'),
        'plazo': get_text(root, './/dPlazoCre', ''),
        'cuotas': get_text(root, './/dCuotas', ''),
        'rucCli': get_text(root, './/dCodCliente', ''),
        'cliNom': get_text(root, './/dNomRec'),
        'dire': get_text(root, './/dDirRec', '-'),
        'tel': get_text(root, './/dTelRec', ''),
        'mail': get_text(root, './/dEmailRec', ''),
        'tipTransac': get_text(root, './/dDesTipTra'),
        'subtotal': get_text(root, './/dSub10', '0'),
        'subtotalMe': get_text(root, './/dSub10', '0'),
        'totalOp': get_text(root, './/dTotOpe', '0'),
        'totalOpMe': get_text(root, './/dTotOpe', '0'),
        'total': get_text(root, './/dTotGralOpe', '0'),
        'totalMe': get_text(root, './/dTotGralOpe', '0'),
        'descuento': get_text(root, './/dDescTotal', '0'),
        'descuentoMe': get_text(root, './/dDescTotal', '0'),
        'urlLogo': 'G:\Server-report\Reports\80010184-7\logo\logo.png',
    }
    return data


I extract all the data from an xml, except for some data
`<DE Id="01800334973001001000308012024052811336721411">
<dDVId>1</dDVId>
<dFecFirma>2024-05-28T09:18:17</dFecFirma>
<dSisFact>1</dSisFact>
<gOpeDE>
<iTipEmi>1</iTipEmi>
<dDesTipEmi>Normal</dDesTipEmi>
<dCodSeg>133672141</dCodSeg>
</gOpeDE>
<gTimb>
<iTiDE>1</iTiDE>
<dDesTiDE>Factura electrónica</dDesTiDE>
<dNumTim>17109678</dNumTim>
<dEst>001</dEst>
<dPunExp>001</dPunExp>
<dNumDoc>0003080</dNumDoc>
<dFeIniT>2024-03-21</dFeIniT>
</gTimb>
<gDatGralOpe>
<dFeEmiDE>2024-05-28T09:16:29</dFeEmiDE>
<gOpeCom>
<iTipTra>1</iTipTra>
<dDesTipTra>Venta de mercadería</dDesTipTra>
<iTImp>5</iTImp>
<dDesTImp>IVA - Renta</dDesTImp>
<cMoneOpe>PYG</cMoneOpe>
<dDesMoneOpe>Guarani</dDesMoneOpe>
<iCondAnt>1</iCondAnt>
<dDesCondAnt>Anticipo Global</dDesCondAnt>
</gOpeCom>
<gEmis>
<dRucEm>80033497</dRucEm>
<dDVEmi>3</dDVEmi>
<iTipCont>1</iTipCont>
<cTipReg>8</cTipReg>
<dNomEmi>INOXPAR S.R.L.</dNomEmi>
<dDirEmi>DEFENSORES DEL CHACO</dDirEmi>
<dNumCas>467</dNumCas>
<cDepEmi>12</cDepEmi>
<dDesDepEmi>CENTRAL</dDesDepEmi>
<cDisEmi>165</cDisEmi>
<dDesDisEmi>VILLA ELISA</dDesDisEmi>
<cCiuEmi>6049</cCiuEmi>
<dDesCiuEmi>VILLA ELISA</dDesCiuEmi>
<dTelEmi>021944333</dTelEmi>
<dEmailE>facturacion.inoxparsrl@gmail.com</dEmailE>
<gActEco>
<cActEco>46699</cActEco>
<dDesActEco>COMERCIO AL POR MAYOR DE OTROS PRODUCTOS N.C.P.</dDesActEco>
</gActEco>
<gRespDE>
<iTipIDRespDE>1</iTipIDRespDE>
<dDTipIDRespDE>Cédula paraguaya</dDTipIDRespDE>
<dNumIDRespDE>571977</dNumIDRespDE>
<dNomRespDE>ALIPIO R. IBARRA IBARRA</dNomRespDE>
<dCarRespDE>REPRESENTANTE LEGAL</dCarRespDE>
</gRespDE>
</gEmis>
<gDatRec>
<iNatRec>1</iNatRec>
<iTiOpe>2</iTiOpe>
<cPaisRec>PRY</cPaisRec>
<dDesPaisRe>Paraguay</dDesPaisRe>
<iTiContRec>2</iTiContRec>
<dRucRec>80007165</dRucRec>
<dDVRec>4</dDVRec>
<dNomRec>TECNIMET S.A</dNomRec>
<dDirRec>Calle Coronel Martinez Luque Paraguay. Km 73</dDirRec>
<dNumCasRec>0</dNumCasRec>
<cDepRec>1</cDepRec>
<dDesDepRec>CAPITAL</dDesDepRec>
<cDisRec>1</cDisRec>
<dDesDisRec>ASUNCION (DISTRITO)</dDesDisRec>
<cCiuRec>1</cCiuRec>
<dDesCiuRec>ASUNCION (DISTRITO)</dDesCiuRec>
<dEmailRec>administracion@tecnimet.com</dEmailRec>
<dCodCliente>80007165-4</dCodCliente>
</gDatRec>
</gDatGralOpe>
<gDtipDE>
<gCamFE>
<iIndPres>1</iIndPres>
<dDesIndPres>Operación presencial</dDesIndPres>
<dFecEmNR>2024-05-28</dFecEmNR>
</gCamFE>
<gCamCond>
<iCondOpe>2</iCondOpe>
<dDCondOpe>Crédito</dDCondOpe>
<gPaConEIni>
<iTiPago>1</iTiPago>
<dDesTiPag>Efectivo</dDesTiPag>
<dMonTiPag>0</dMonTiPag>
<cMoneTiPag>PYG</cMoneTiPag>
<dDMoneTiPag>Guarani</dDMoneTiPag>
</gPaConEIni>
<gPagCred>
<iCondCred>1</iCondCred>
<dDCondCred>Plazo</dDCondCred>
<dPlazoCre>30 días</dPlazoCre>
<dMonEnt>0</dMonEnt>
</gPagCred>
</gCamCond>
<gCamItem>
<dCodInt>070-00031</dCodInt>
<dDesProSer>CHAPA ANTID. DE ALUM. 3003 H26 DE 1,50MM 1.250 X 3.000</dDesProSer>
<cUniMed>77</cUniMed>
<dDesUniMed>UNI</dDesUniMed>
<dCantProSer>10.0000</dCantProSer>
<cPaisOrig>PRY</cPaisOrig>
<dDesPaisOrig>Paraguay</dDesPaisOrig>
<dCanQuiMer>0</dCanQuiMer>
<dPorQuiMer>0</dPorQuiMer>
<gValorItem>
<dPUniProSer>880000.00000000</dPUniProSer>
<dTotBruOpeItem>8800000.00000000</dTotBruOpeItem>
<gValorRestaItem>
<dDescItem>0.00000000</dDescItem>
<dPorcDesIt>0.00000000</dPorcDesIt>
<dDescGloItem>0</dDescGloItem>
<dAntPreUniIt>0</dAntPreUniIt>
<dAntGloPreUniIt>0</dAntGloPreUniIt>
<dTotOpeItem>8800000.00000000</dTotOpeItem>
<dTotOpeGs>0</dTotOpeGs>
</gValorRestaItem>
</gValorItem>
<gCamIVA>
<iAfecIVA>1</iAfecIVA>
<dDesAfecIVA>Gravado IVA</dDesAfecIVA>
<dPropIVA>100</dPropIVA>
<dTasaIVA>10</dTasaIVA>
<dBasGravIVA>8000000.00000000</dBasGravIVA>
<dLiqIVAItem>800000.00000000</dLiqIVAItem>
<dBasExe>0</dBasExe>
</gCamIVA>
<gRasMerc/>
</gCamItem>
<gCamEsp>
<gGrupEner>
<dNroMed>0</dNroMed>
<dActiv>0</dActiv>
<dCateg>0</dCateg>
<dLecAnt>0</dLecAnt>
<dLecAct>0</dLecAct>
<dConKwh>0</dConKwh>
</gGrupEner>
</gCamEsp>
<gTransp>
<iModTrans>1</iModTrans>
<dDesModTrans>Terrestre</dDesModTrans>
<iRespFlete>1</iRespFlete>
</gTransp>
</gDtipDE>
<gTotSub>
<dSubExe>0.00000000</dSubExe>
<dSubExo>0</dSubExo>
<dSub5>0.00000000</dSub5>
<dSub10>8800000.00000000</dSub10>
<dTotOpe>8800000.00000000</dTotOpe>
<dTotDesc>0.00000000</dTotDesc>
<dTotDescGlotem>0</dTotDescGlotem>
<dTotAntItem>0</dTotAntItem>
<dTotAnt>0</dTotAnt>
<dPorcDescTotal>0</dPorcDescTotal>
<dDescTotal>0.00000000</dDescTotal>
<dAnticipo>0</dAnticipo>
<dRedon>0</dRedon>
<dComi>0</dComi>
<dTotGralOpe>8800000.00000000</dTotGralOpe>
<dIVA5>0.00000000</dIVA5>
<dIVA10>800000.00000000</dIVA10>
<dLiqTotIVA5>0</dLiqTotIVA5>
<dLiqTotIVA10>0</dLiqTotIVA10>
<dIVAComi>0</dIVAComi>
<dTotIVA>800000.00000000</dTotIVA>
<dBaseGrav5>0.00000000</dBaseGrav5>
<dBaseGrav10>8000000.00000000</dBaseGrav10>
<dTBasGraIVA>8000000.00000000</dTBasGraIVA>
</gTotSub>
<gCamGen>
<gCamCarg/>
</gCamGen>
</DE>`

Please help me to fix this shit

Es un proyecto en django, que estoy intentando compilar los reportes en jasper y pasarlos a una ventana del navegador como pdf, pero en sí el problema que tengo es el del título, gracias

Usa el custom que te da Facturasend, te vas a ahorrar muchos problemas.

Estás en [es.so]: recuerda que el idioma del sitio es el español, por lo tanto las líneas en inglés no corresponden. ¿Intentaste hacer la prueba sin pasar el número de timbrado como parámetro, a ver si aparece algún otro error?
